# List of Structure as a DataGrid DataSource VB2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, list, data-binding, datagridview

It's my first time playing with the DataGridView properly and I've hit a little snag...
I need to display data in a DataGridView for ease of viewing, and I have a list of all the data. It's a list (of *a structure*), and I've got no idea how to do this. I can set the datasource as the list, but that doesn't work. I've read up on the topic but don't really understand. Am I forced to use classes not structures in this instance?

Another issue is that the data in the list isn't all needed... I'll need to sort the list first and only put in the stuff that's needed.

Would it be a better idea to manually populate the grid, rather than use a source in this instance?

Thanks.

Comment: I've just manually populated it now. Was very easy and more like the thing I was looking for. However, I will be using DGs more often in the future, so if anyone can enlighten me really on what the whole business is with using classes and properties I'd be very happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a structure as a datasource is almost certainly a really bad idea, because you will make multiple deep copies of the object in your datasource in the process of binding to your presentation object. That has horrendous performance implications. Changing from a Structure to a Class will also likely make it easier to figure out what you're doing wrong with your data source, but here are some things to try:

- Try using a BindingSource object (to help map properties of your actual object to columns the DataGridView should show
- Try setting the AutoGenerateColumns property to True, or, alternatively:
- Make sure you have a columns collection that *exactly* matches the property names of the object in your list
- Make sure the object type in your list has a good overload for the .ToString() function
- Make sure the type of any properties of the object type in your list have good overloads for the .ToString() function.